# Нижнее подчёркивание

Tags: html, javascript

Что означает нижнее подчёркивание. Вот фрагмент скрипта
`<script src="_javascript/tonegenerator2_0.js?1387518803"></script>`

Comment: Название папки? Папка: `_javascript` Файл скрипта: `tonegenerator2_0.js` GET-переменная: `?1387518803`
.
GET скорее всего нужна для того чтобы браузер не кешировал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал уже Олег Б, это название папки, сделан с целью,чтобы браузер не кешировал.